# How do I setNamingStrategy on Dropwizard HibernateBundle class without xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard

I am working on a project that uses dropwizard's hibernate bundle to get a session factory per the below docs:

http://www.dropwizard.io/0.7.1/docs/manual/hibernate.html

The project doesn't use any xml and only uses annotated classes for the configuration of the bundle just like in the example.

```
public class ExampleConfiguration extends Configuration {
     @Valid
     @NotNull
     @JsonProperty("database")
     private DataSourceFactory database = new DataSourceFactory();

     public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
         return database;
     }
}

private final HibernateBundle<ExampleConfiguration> hibernate = 
new HibernateBundle<ExampleConfiguration>(
    some.class
    ) {
    @Override
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(ExampleConfiguration configuration) {
    return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
    }
};
```

However, we have a use case where I need to prepend the environment to the table name of the DAO objects such that the @Table annotation gets overwritten.

I have a class which implements ImprovedNamingStrategy, per the below docs

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html

But how do I hook the naming strategy into my dropwizard hibernate bundle. I would like to be able to do something like this...

```
hibernateBundle.setNamingStrategy(ImprovedNamingStrategy.Instance)
```

or

```
hibernateBundle.addAnnotatedClass(someHibernateNamingPropertyConfig)
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#setNamingStrategy(org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy)

However, the hibernateBundle API doesn't allow for any of this.

Looking through the source code of HibernateBundle

https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-hibernate/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/hibernate/HibernateBundle.java

You can see that it uses "import io.dropwizard.Configuration;" as opposed to org.hibernate.cfg which does expose all of these methods. I'm trying to avoid a major refactor so if there is a "hacky" way to force set the naming property on the bundle, then I'm okay with that.

Any ideas of where to go from here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution for this that works for me **in Dropwizard 0.8.4**. Not sure if it can help you with Dropwizard 0.7.1, but it will definitely be helpful for readers coming from Google with the same question.

You can extend `HibernateBundle` and override `configure()`. This method is called just before SessionFactoryFactory is going to be built, with the `Configuration` object for it. You can then override the method to add any special configurations you might need.

Example:

```
public abstract class DatabaseWithImprovedNamingStrategyBundle extends ScanningHibernateBundle {
  public DatabaseWithImprovedNamingStrategyBundle(String pckg) {
    super(pckg);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(Configuration configuration) {
    super.configure(configuration);
    configuration.setNamingStrategy(ImprovedNamingStrategy.INSTANCE);
  }
}
```

This example uses ScanningHibernateBundle because it's the one I was using, but you can use HibernateBundle directly too.

Comment: Sorry, but how do you use this? I tried applying this to the OPs version but it doesn't accept a list of ClassFile.class in the constructor anymore. Can you tell me how you would put this into practice inside the Configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

I just decided not to use the Hibernate Bundle and create a second config object which reads values out of the Hibernate Bundle.

Comment: Can you modify your question with your answer or post it as an answer?